# Closing a Dialog Form and Open another form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've got (what I believe to be) a weird issue with closing a form and opening another.

I have a button on a particular form (that is opened using the `.ShowDialog` if that makes any difference), when the button is clicked, the following code runs:

```
Me.Close()
LC.ShowDialog()
```

I would expect that the form containing the button should close and the `LC` form should open as a dialog form. What actually happens is that the `Me` form stays open and the `LC` form appears behind it with main focus.

Why would this be?

**UPDATE 1**

Just to clarify the set up of the forms:

- Form1 opens the `me` form as a Dialog (Where Form1 is the main form that is launched on startup)
- The `me` form opens the `LC` form and should close in the process

Comment: A dialog requires an owner window, one that can stay on top of.  A closed form cannot be that owner so a Z-order accident is not unlikely.  Why you can still see it after you called Close() most certainly requires http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it seems you might have a conception issue...

Let's get this through, if you call me.close(), you are asking your form to terminate itself, and to kill all forms he generated.
However, it is not direct, a windows Message is posted to your application that will be treated whenever you function is done.

Then right after that, you create a new form and you say you want to wait for it to close to continue.

I don't know what your purpose is but you have a few solutions :

- If you want to go back to your main form (Form1) when done with LC :

  ```
  Me.Hide()
  LC.ShowDialog()
  =>Your code will pick up here when LC will be closed
  Me.Show()
  ```
- If you don't want your Form1 to open ever again, then don't make it your starting form, or start working in the Sub Main()

Comment: Thanks, I changed the last `Me.show()` to `Me.Close()` and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

make the form1 a flowmanager of the forms. I mean, form1 should opens the lc and close the me.

Comment: It doesn't matter which way round I put the two lines, the issue is the same. Infact, doing it the other way round I'd expect the `me` form to stay open as the other form is a Dialog and no additional code will run until that form is closed

Answer (score -2):

You must call both Dialog Forms from a parent form.
You may do something like this:

**PARENT FORM**

```
  FirstDialog.Showdialog
  (the app will open this dialog and wait it close)

  SecondDialog.Showdialog
```

Doing this way the second dialog will open ONLY when the first one be closed.
You cannot start another dialog from a dialog being closed.

Good luck